# Elliptic regularity of Laplace-Beltrami operator on a manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, operator-theory, elliptic-pde

I am currently trying to prove an elliptic regularity type result for the Laplace Beltrami operator $\Delta_g$ on a Riemannian manifold $(M^n,g)$. As a matter of convention, I will assume $\Delta_g$ to be a nonpositive (self-adjoint) unbounded operator on $L^2(M)$, with domain $$
\mathcal{D}(\Delta_g):=\{f\in L^2(M)\ :\ \Delta_g f\in L^2(M)\}
$$ where we define $\Delta_g f\in\mathcal{D}'(M)$ by using symmetry of $\Delta_g$ and taking the formal adjoint. Then by functional calculus, we can define a semigroup $$
[0,\infty)\to\mathscr{L}(L^2(M)),\quad t\mapsto e^{t\Delta_g}
$$ which is strongly continuous, and continuous in norm for $t>0$. Now, I have shown that $e^{t\Delta_g}$ is smooth as a function of $t$, with $$
\frac{\mathrm d^k}{\mathrm d t^k}e^{t\Delta_g} = \Delta_g^k e^{t\Delta_g}\in\mathscr{L}(L^2(M))
$$ as a derivative, however, it is less clear to me how to prove smoothness in space. My issue is that I can only see how to define $e^{t\Delta_g}$ via the spectral theorem. This is done by fixing a unitary map $U:L^2(M)\to L^2(X,\mu)$ for some measure space $(X,\mu)$, and fixing some measurable $g:X\to(-\infty,0]$ such that the multiplication operator $M_g$ corresponds to $\Delta_g$, and by setting $e^{t\Delta_g}$ to correspond with $M_{e^{tg}}\in\mathscr{L}(L^2(X,\mu))$.

Can smoothness of $u:=e^{t\Delta_g}f$ be proved from the fact that $\Delta_g^k u\in L^2(M)$ for all $k\ge0$, or is more needed?

Comment: There are other ways to construct the heat kernel, see for instance the book by Berline, Getzler and Vergne.

Comment: Check out Chapter 4 of Taylor's book *Partial Differential Equations*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about M? I will give an answer supposing it is compact without boundary.

You want to prove that for fixed $t\in \mathbb{R}$, $e^{t\Delta}f\in C^\infty(M)$. This comes from an eigenvalue estimate of the Laplacian + elliptic regularity. For $-\Delta$ (positive Laplacian), due to the compactness of the manifold and Sobolev Embedding theorem you have that the Laplacian is Discrete operator with $\lambda_j \geq Cj^c, c>0$ (For your Laplacian you get the opposite). (A proof of this you can find on the book "Invariance theory, Heat equation and the Atiyah-Singer Index Theorem" Ch. 1.6)

Now on M you have Sobolev Embedding that states $H^{k+m}\hookrightarrow C^k$ and using that $e^{t\Delta}f(x) = \sum_j e^{t\lambda_j}\psi_j(x)<f,\psi_j>$ you can easily show that $\Delta^k e^{t\Delta}f = e^{t\Delta} \Delta^kf$ (For this you need the eigenvalue estimate, because it shows that $\sum_j \lambda_j^ke^{t\lambda_j}$ converges absolutely for every k.

But now you have that $\Delta^k (e^{t\Delta}f)\in L^2(M)\Rightarrow (e^{t\Delta}f)\in H^{2k}(M) \ \forall\ k$ and by Sobolev Embedding you get smoothness.